# How to Sort Values in Descending Order in a Grafana Stat Dashboard with a Loki Query?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql, grafana-dashboard

I am currently using a Loki query to fetch the top 10 error messages from my systems and display them on a Grafana stat dashboard. The query I am using is:

```
topk(10, sum by(message)(count_over_time({job="systemd-journal"} |~ `ERROR:` | regexp `(?P<message>ERROR:.*)` [7d])))
```

The output I receive successfully retrieves the top 10 error messages, but the values are not sorted in any particular order, as can be seen in the attached screenshot.
[image: Dashboard]
[image: Settings]

I expected the topk function to automatically sort the values in a descending order, but that doesn't seem to be happening. I have looked through the Grafana and Loki documentation but could not find a straightforward way to sort the values within the stat panel in Grafana. I am seeking a method or a query adjustment that would enable me to display these values sorted in a descending order.

To provide more information on the transformation drop down "Sort by":
[image: Drop Down 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish your task:

1. Sort using logql. You can use [functions `sort` and `sort_desc`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#built-in-aggregation-operators) over your query, to provided a sorted result to Grafana to visualize. AFAIK, Grafana preserves order of data in dataset unless instructed otherwise.
   You query will be

```
sort_desc(
 topk(10,
      sum by(message) (
        count_over_time(
          {job="systemd-journal"} |~ `ERROR:` | regexp `(?P<message>ERROR:.*)` 
          [7d]))))
```

2. You can use Transformation [*Sort by*](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#sort-by) on your panel. It will sort data based on selected column (in your case something like `Value #A` I believe)

For this approach to work you need to set Type of query (under query itself in collapsible menu) to **Instant**. Also if you'll see a single datapoint on panel after that, in panel options: Value options>Show select **All values**.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried using the sort and sort_desc functions without success. When utilizing these functions, I receive the following error: parse error at line 1, col 1: syntax error: unexpected IDENTIFIER.
As for the "Sort by" transformation in Grafana, it appears that I don't have the option to filter by the value field to sort the results accordingly. It only allows me to filter by numeric fields, which are not available in my case.
Is there perhaps another method or pathway I might be overlooking to achieve the desired sorting?I would be grateful for any further assistance

Comment: @LuisFalke, I'm not following Loki releases closely, but here is PR that introduced sort function: https://github.com/grafana/loki/pull/7989, maybe you can identify required minimal version out of it.

Comment: Regarding numeric fields: your query returns at least one numeric field - value of metrics. It should be available for selection in the drop down (named like `Value #A`). If it's missing from there - it's something out of the ordinary, maybe you can share a screenshot of that?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. I have provided the screenshots in the edited version of the question for you to check out.

Comment: @LuisFalke, aha, that clarified things a bit: you need to switch type of query to *Instant* (this is done under the query itself). Also if you'll see a single datapoint on panel after that, in panel options: Value options>Show>All values.